# How do you compile a contract that uses Open Zeppelin's Standard Token in Truffle?

Tags: truffle, tokens, openzeppelin, truffle-compile

Compiling is failing.

`vi contracts/MyCoin.sol`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import 'zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol';

contract MyCoin is StandardToken {
  string public name = "MyCoin";
  string public symbol = "MC";
  uint public decimals = 2;
  uint public INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000 * (10 ** decimals);

  function MyCoin() public {
    totalSupply = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
  }
}
```

When I run `truffle compile`:

```
➜  my-coin truffle compile  
Compiling ./contracts/MyCoin.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/BasicToken.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Basic.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol...

/Users/pedro/src/my-coin/contracts/MyCoin.sol:13:5: TypeError: No matching declaration found after variable lookup.
    totalSupply = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    ^---------^
Compilation failed. See above.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OZ has updated their code besides restructuring some of the folders.

**Old Answer (pre 2.X.X release)**

Look here: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/BasicToken.sol

Your direct answer: `totalSupply_` (the underscore) is the variable name you're looking for.

**Current Answer Update (12/11/18):**

```
uint256 private _totalSupply;

/**
* @dev Total number of tokens in existence
*/
function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
    return _totalSupply;
}
```

New Link: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v2.0.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

OZ has refactored their repo ever since v2.X.X release

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. Use this instead: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/v2.0.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

Answer (score 1):

Total supply variable is defined as a function. Modify your code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import 'zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol';

contract MyCoin is StandardToken {
  string public name = "MyCoin";
  string public symbol = "MC";
  uint public decimals = 2;
  uint public INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000 * (10 ** decimals);

  function MyCoin() public {
    totalSupply_ = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
  }
}
```